# contact form is overlapping the footer

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The contact form is overlapping the entire footer. I ran the code on codepen and it was working like normal. the stylesheet is connected and working so all other styling works except for the contact form, i've tried repositioning the padding, bottom etc but nothing works.

Can anyone see anything wrong in the code ? Or can anyone suggest what I have to do to fix it ?

```
<!-- second container-->
<div class="container-fluid" id="jumbotron2">              
    <div class="row">               
        <div class="col-lg-12">               
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card text-center mb-3">
                    <div class="card-body text-dark">
                        <h1 class="card-title text-warning">Web Services</h1><br>
                        <p class="card-text"> I make custom websites tailored to your needs for 
  the following:
                        <ul class="text-left">
                            <li>E-commerce</li> 
                            <li>Social media sites</li>  
                            <li>Blog sites</li> 
                            <li>Online business brochures</li> 
                            <li>Self-employed and</li>  
                            <li>Companies</li> 
                        </ul>
                        <!-- 
                            <a href="website.html" role="button"class="btn btn-warning">more information</a 
                         -->
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="card text-center mb-3">
                     <div class="card-body text-dark">
                         <h2 class="card-title text-warning">IT distance support</h2><br>
                         <p class="card-text">
                            Virtual machines and servers, active directory, windows server 2012
                            <ul class="text-left">
                                <li>Create & manage user accounts</li>
                                <li>Group policy management</li>
                                <li>Install and configure</li>
                                <li>Manager server roles</li>
                                <li>Manage server shares</li>
                            </ul>
                            <br><br>
                            <!-- 
                                <a href="re-design.html" role="button" class="btn btn-warning">more information</a> 
                            -->   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card text-center mb-3">
                        <div class="card-body text-dark">
                            <h2 class="card-title text-warning">Web Hosting</h2><br>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                Hosting your website live on the internet
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <ul class="text-left">
                                    <li>Reasonably priced hosting packages</li>
                                    <li>guaranteed 99% uptime</li>
                                    <li>fast page loading</li>
                                    <li>unlimited storage</li>
                                </ul>

                                <!--
                                    <a href="hosting.html" role="button" class="btn btn-warning">more 
  information</a>    
                                -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <!-- contact form -->
        <div class="container" id="contact">
            <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'> 
        </script>
        <div class="form-row">      
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <h2>Contact me for a free quote</h2> 
                <p> Send your message in the form below and i will get back 
 to you as soon as possible. </p>
                <br>          
                <p>Choose from the following :</p>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
 name="inlineRadioOptions1" id="inlineRadio1" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" 
 for="inlineRadio1">New Website</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
 name="inlineRadioOptions1" id="inlineRadio2" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" 
 for="inlineRadio2">IT Support</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
 name="inlineRadioOptions1" id="inlineRadio3" value="">
                    <label class="form-check-label" 
 for="inlineRadio3">Website Hosting</label>
                </div>
                <form role="form" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"> Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
  name="name" required maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"> address:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" 
  name="address" required maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"> phone:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" 
 name="phone" required maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email"> Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" 
 name="email" required maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name"> Message:</label>     <!--removed 
 type="textarea"-->
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" 
id="message" placeholder="Your Message Here" maxlength="6000" rows="7"> 
</textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data- 
  sitekey=""></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning 
   pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Post It! &rarr;</button>
                </form>
                <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; 
   display:none; "> <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3> </div>
                <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; 
   display:none; "> <h3>Error</h3> Sorry there was an error sending your 
 form. 
  </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  #jumbotron  {           
    padding-top: 50px;
    height: 100px;
  }

  #jumbotron2 {               
   padding-top: 150px;
   height: 300px;
   margin-bottom: 250px;
   }

  #contact {                    
  padding-top: 250px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-bottom: 250px; 
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the relevant code and CSS so that we can see what is wrong?

Comment: Hi Girish, sorry i am new to this site. I have provided the code that relates directly to the problem. In fact, when i first published the website, there was no issue, everything worked fine except the contact form. Now suddenly, with no changes to the code, the contact form completely overhangs the footer. I check it on codepen.io and the code is fine so i don't understand what happened.

Comment: can u share that codepen link

Comment: Yes i can. https://codepen.io/DevelopeurMarco/pen/yxBmMY    - i just checked code again, and this time you can see the contact form overlap the footer PLUS half of the head has now disappeared

Comment: remove `height: 500px` from class `#contact {.....}`, it will work fine :)

Comment: Thank you GIrish your idea worked

Answer (score 0):

Please remove fixed height set in class `#contact {.....}` as show below. it overlaps the inner content or add 'overflow: hidden' to it.

```css
#jumbotron {
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

#jumbotron2 {
  padding-top: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 250px;
}

#contact {
  padding-top: 250px;
  /* height: 500px; */
  /* Remove this fixed height set to the container, it overlaps the inner content or add 'overflow: hidden' to it. */
  margin-bottom: 250px;
}
```